# Wordpress Password Reset SSL Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I'm using the standard Wordpress password reset process, i.e. request new password through email submission and then reset the password with the link provided which includes a password reset key, i.e. it provides a link as follows:

delivered email states:

```
To re-set your password, visit the following address:
<http://example.com/resetpass/?key=Yccndncnsdkjfnsdkjnfkjsndfk&login=theUsername>
http://example.com
```

This works fine when not using SSL however when SSL is enabled it strips out the key and gives an error that the key is no longer valid. Does anyone know how to solve this, i've found a number of questions with the same problem but no solutions?

Comment: have your tried enable your SSL first and then reset your password ?